# Graphical Layout tab does not appear for some layout files into Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, user-interface, layout, adt

I'm facing a problem when developing layout files for Android with Eclipse ADT Plugin. Some of my files, when opened, does not show the Graphical layout tab, just as below:

[image]

The others (actually, the older ones), instead, show it correctly.

[image]

Does anyone knows what can be done in this case?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This may be a permanent solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152046/android-xml-editors-broken-in-eclipse/8152113#8152113

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Have you tried **right clicking one of the layout files** in the Package Explorer view and clicking

**`Open With -> Android Layout Editor`**

Comment: Thanks very much, man! I just can't figure out why these files are now being opened with the other editor. Older files are opened with the Android Layout Editor as expected.

Comment: I've had the same problem man, it seems eclipse has a mind of its own when it comes to opening android xml files!

Comment: I just started having this same issue. Your solution worked. Thanks!

Comment: I also have the same problem after updating to ADT 14. After trying the suggestion It works thanks it save my life.

Comment: I had the same problem - it worked for me only after first opening with Android Layout Editor as per your answer (which gave a blank editor window) and then also restarting Eclipse, at which point everything's fine again.  Thanks!

Comment: Whilst this works, is there no way to resolve this permanently? I used to be able to double-click an xml file and have it open correctly, but now I have to right-click etc. Its a massive pain! Tried fresh install!

Comment: `Android Layout Editor` doesn't exist anymore.  It appears to now be `Android Common XML Editor`.

Answer (score 3):

If you can see the Graphical Editor tab and still if nothing is showing up, restart eclipse.
Worked for me!