# Layout editor does not open in eclipse with adt 15.0

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin

[Graphical Layout tab does not appear for some layout files into Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715802/graphical-layout-tab-does-not-appear-for-some-layout-files-into-eclipse)

I tried right click -> open with layout editor but the graphical layout remain blank

Comment: refresh or close that layout.xml and again open using double click on that file.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work. Only a particular project's xml does not open in graphical layout

Comment: try deleting the project and importing it again. Might work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better duplicate the file and rewrite the code... Even my XML file got corrupted and this way i replicated and rewrote the code to make it working.. Weird ad logicless but yeah that worked for me. so you ma try that