# error while creating xml file in eclipse for android project

Tags: android, eclipse

I had created a project in my laptop.
The project was working properly in the laptop.

Now I transfer the project to my desktop
The project still working properly.

But the issue is that, when I want to create a new xml file the following error is shown:

> [2012-03-01 08:49:05 - final_project] Error in an XML file: aborting build.
>   [2012-03-01 08:49:09 - final_project]     (skipping index file 'H:\final_project\MUNJAL
>   \final_project\res\drawable-hdpi\Thumbs.db')
>   [2012-03-01 08:49:09 - final_project]     (skipping index file 'H:\final_project\MUNJAL
>   \final_project\res\drawable-ldpi\Thumbs.db')
>   [2012-03-01 08:49:09 - final_project] res\layout\NewFile.xml: Invalid file name: must >contain only [a-z0-9_.]
>   [2012-03-01 08:49:09 - final_project] res\layout\NewFile.xml: Invalid file name: must >contain only [a-z0-9_.]
>   [2012-03-01 08:49:09 - final_project] H:\final_project\MUNJAL\final_project\res\layout
>   \NewFile.xml:2: error: Error parsing XML: no element found
>   [2012-03-01 08:52:33 - final_project]     (skipping index file 'H:\final_project\MUNJAL
>   \final_project\res\drawable-hdpi\Thumbs.db')
>   [2012-03-01 08:52:33 - final_project]     (skipping index file 'H:\final_project\MUNJAL
>   \final_project\res\drawable-ldpi\Thumbs.db')
>   [2012-03-01 08:52:33 - final_project] res\layout\NewFile.xml: Invalid file name: must >contain only [a-z0-9_.]
>   [2012-03-01 08:52:33 - final_project] res\layout\NewFile.xml: Invalid file name: must >contain only [a-z0-9_.]
>   [2012-03-01 08:52:33 - final_project] H:\final_project\MUNJAL\final_project\res\layout
>   \NewFile.xml:2: error: Error parsing XML: no element found

Even the Design view of the previously created xml file does not show any design.

I am new to Android development, so I feel sorry if it is very easy/foolish question
I have tried to solve it but could not get success

Thanks ...

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the filename must be all lower case as indicated by the error.

```
name: must >contain only [a-z0-9_.]
```

Comment: Do you have any xml elements in your file?

Answer (score 0):

1) the above error is because of there is no content in the xml file. some version of eclipse 
   add the basic content but some other versions do not add the basic contents like

> LinearLayout>
>
> xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>   android:layout_width="match_parent"
>   android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical"
>   android:id="@+id/uClere"/>

2) the Design view of the previously created xml file do not shows any design, it is solved by following link...

[Graphical Layout tab does not appear for some layout files into Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715802/graphical-layout-tab-does-not-appear-for-some-layout-files-into-eclipse)

thanks  Milhous .

thanks to all ...