# Graphical Layout of XML not showing when i install updates Android

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

Android: Graphical layout of XML file is not showing up, this happened when i installed updates and SDK tools from SDK manager.

I searched on google. But i am not getting the answer which can help me.

Kindly help me i am kinda stuck in my work.

Comment: @user1523227-Just show your code which u have tried .

Comment: [this?][1]

also you can do it by keyboard but i forgot the sequance
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715802/graphical-layout-tab-does-not-appear-for-some-layout-files-into-eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your ADT also then restart your IDE(eclipse), then it will show.

Comment: waht am i gonna do next..?

Comment: Under Help-> Install New Software, add this "Android - ADT - https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/" then update, it will update your ADt to latest version available.